# Using javascript method in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to call method: :delete on a custom url where I will pass a parameter id in that link_to method. My controller name is "boxelements" and controller method will be "ruin", the javascript method is "delete"

It will be similar like this

```
    <%= link_to image_tag('delete.png'),url,method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

I need to define "url" variable here What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

What's `bundle exec rake routes` gives you?

If you have your custom rails action in a resource like:

```
  # in config/routes.rb

  resources :boxelements do
    delete :ruin
  end
```

You can use something like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('delete.png'), boxelement_ruin_path(id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following way worked for me. url_for method did that task of generating url.

```
    <% url = url_for(:controller => 'boxelements', :action =>'ruin',:id => id) %>
    <%= link_to image_tag('delete.png'),url,method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```